# What potting mixes do you use?

Tags: soil, compost, peat

I am new to gardening and I would like to know what ingredients and measurements do you use in your potting mix for three different types of plants:

- Plants that require plenty of water.
- Plants that require good water draining.
- Plants that need rocky soil.

With respect to plants that require plenty of water, is it a good idea to include peat moss or coconut coir? Moreover, is soil a good water absorbent?

Comment: this depends on what you are growing, where.... Tends to be opinion based as well..voting to close feel free to ask a more specific question like "best soil mix for this type of plant"

Comment: the one on sale at the hardware\garden store at the time i go shopping

Comment: Consider breaking the question up into 3 questions and make it more specific to what you are trying to do vs. a very generic question.  It will help us answer your question.  Voting to close as well

Comment: JStorage is correct, this is to broad, with too many variables. Please split it into three questions, add where you live (generally), and please add specific plants you intend to grow. The reason is that different answers apply to different plants. You asked about plants that like lots of water. Some like to stay wet/damp and some like to get soaked heavily, but then dry out. Both like lots of water, but the answer will kill one and make the other thrive.